# "Escaping" $ when executing a remote bash command from python fabric

Tags: python, bash, fabric

So I am trying to automate the set up of an arch linux instance via a python fabric script like this:

```
from fabric.api import run, sudo

def server_setup_communityrepo():
    run('echo \'echo "[archlinuxfr]" >> /etc/pacman.conf\' | sudo -s')
    run('echo \'echo "Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch" >> /etc/pacman.conf\' | sudo -s')
    run('echo \'echo " " >> /etc/pacman.conf\' | sudo -s')
    sudo('pacman -Syy yaourt --noconfirm')
```

The problem occurs on the second `run()` call because of the $ sign in the `$arch`. This fabric function fails in line 2 because $ followed by a string is recognized by fabric as a config variable.  But I actually want $arch to be understood as a literal in the

`echo 'echo "Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch" >> /etc/pacman.conf'` call in bash shell.

How do I "escape" from this fabric quirk and designate the $arch as a literal to be written into my pacman.conf file?

Comment: Does changing it to `\$` work?

Comment: nope. that's the first thing I tried. doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use echo with single quotes. That will prevent the shell from expanding  `$arch`.

```
run('echo \'Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch\' | sudo -s tee -a /etc/pacman.conf')
```

this should be equivalent to

```
echo 'Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch' | sudo -s tee -a /etc/pacman.conf
```

---

quick testing:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('echo \'Server = /foo/$arch\' ')
Server = /foo/$arch
0
```

Comment: oops. wait a moment. there seems to be a problem.

Comment: unfortunately, this doesn't work because this echo is piped in to the bash shell.

Comment: I modified your command to use tee, instead of the redirection. does it work now ?

Comment: You are the man (or monster if you like :-D), c00kiemon5ter! works perfectly. Much thanks and I should use `tee` more often!!! Nice trick there.