# Python Fabric awk works with local but not run

Tags: awk, fabric

I'm writing a Fabric command to get a list of the users running processes on a machine.  The command works when I run in a shell and also when I use the local function but it errors when I use the run function:

```
from fabric.api import run, env, local

# Works
local("ps auxww | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '{print $2}'")

# Does not work
run("ps auxww | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '{print $2}'")
```

This is the error:

```
Executing task 'get_users'
[localhost] run: ps auxww | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '{print $2}'
[localhost] out: awk: syntax error at source line 1
[localhost] out:  context is
[localhost] out:    {print >>>  \ <<< }
[localhost] out: awk: illegal statement at source line 1
[localhost] out: awk: syntax error at source line 1
[localhost] out:  context is
[localhost] out:    {print >>>  \ <<< }
[localhost] out: awk: illegal statement at source line 1
[localhost] out:
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `run` command with single quotes instead of double quotes. Like:

```
run('ps auxww | awk \'{print $1}\'')
```

See: ["Escaping" $ when executing a remote bash command from python fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10202162/escaping-when-executing-a-remote-bash-command-from-python-fabric)

Comment: Nope that still does not work. I get the same error.

Comment: @ChadVernon Ok. To debug, you could try to replace `$1` with `"Hello"`, and see if the error is still there. (I suspect the error is related to the dollar sign.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
run("ps auxww | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '{print $2}'"
, shell_escape=False)
```